# Slurm node daemon error: Can't open PID file

Tags: slurm

I run `systemctl start slurmd.service`, and it times out:

```
Job for slurmd.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
```

The relevant lines from running `systemctl status slurmd.service`:

```
Mar 23 17:13:42 fedora1 systemd[1]: Starting Slurm node daemon...
Mar 23 17:13:43 fedora1 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/slurm/slurmd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Mar 23 17:15:11 fedora1 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Mar 23 17:15:11 fedora1 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Mar 23 17:15:11 fedora1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Slurm node daemon.
```

The contents of the slurm.conf file:

```
# Put this file on all nodes of your cluster.
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
#SlurmctldHost=fedora1
#
ControlMachine=fedora1
ControlAddr=192.168.1.4
#MailProg=/bin/mail 
MpiDefault=none
#MpiParams=ports=#-# 
ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup
ReturnToService=1
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
#SlurmctldPort=6817 
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
#SlurmdPort=6818 
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd
SlurmUser=slurm
#SlurmdUser=root 
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurmctld
SwitchType=switch/none
TaskPlugin=task/affinity
# 
# 
# TIMERS 
#KillWait=30 
#MinJobAge=300 
#SlurmctldTimeout=120 
#SlurmdTimeout=300 
# 
# 
# SCHEDULING 
FastSchedule=1
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
# 
# 
# LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING 
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
ClusterName=fedora
#JobAcctGatherFrequency=30 
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
#SlurmctldDebug=info 
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurmctld.log
#SlurmdDebug=info 
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurmd.log
# 
# 
# COMPUTE NODES 
NodeName=fedora1 NodeAddr=192.168.1.4 CPUs=1 State=UNKNOWN
NodeName=fedora2 NodeAddr=192.168.1.5 CPUs=1 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=debug Nodes=fedora[1-2] Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

Comment: @nasir-riley I tried what you suggested, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Please look at the error message again.

Comment: I don't know what I did, but now it works.

Answer (score 5):

Your `slurmd.service` file is specifying `/var/run/slurm/slurmd.pid` whereas your `slurm.conf` file is specifying `/var/run/slurmd.pid`.

In the `slurm.conf` file, change this line:

`SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid`

to this:

`SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurm/slurmd.pid`

And then start the service.